# Jungle River Metric contains no countable, dense subset

Tags: general-topology

I have to show that Jungle River Metric is not a separable space.
According to the definition separable space contains a countable, dense subset.

I preset my idea: we know that $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$. So we have to prove that $ \exists p\in \mathbb{R}^2 \exists \epsilon>0 \forall q\in\mathbb{Q}^2 d_{r}\left( p,q\right) \ge \epsilon$ (where $d_{r}$ is Jungle River Metric). However we may take $p=(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3})$ and $\epsilon = 1$ and as a result we don't have any $q \in \mathbb{Q}^2$. So we have contradiction.

However I am not sure it is enough to prove, becuase I think that we may find such subset when we have the case: $x_1 \neq y_1 $.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: What is Jungle River metric?

Comment: @pmun See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092807/show-that-the-jungle-river-barbed-wire-metric-is-a-metric) for the definition and some other properties. \

Comment: @Margaret I request you to add the link above to your post, it will be helpful for others too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For every $x \in \Bbb R$, the set $U_x = \{x\} \times (1,+\infty)$ is open in this metric, easily checked. They are disjoint for distinct $x$. Conclude that a dense subset must have at least $|\Bbb R|$ many points.