# Every open set in Euclidean space is also open in space with Jungle River metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is it true that every open set in Euclidean space $\left(\mathbb{R}^2, \lVert\cdot \lVert_{2} \right)$,  is also open in space $\left(\mathbb{R}^2, d_{r} \right)$, where $d_{r}$ is jungle river metric?

I may have found an example proving that it's not true and I would like to know if it's correct.

I took into consideration examples of open balls $B((0,0),1)$ (diamond and circle). But there is a point $x \in B((0,0),1)$ in $\left(\mathbb{R}^2, \lVert\cdot \lVert_{2} \right)$, which doesn't belongs to diamond and we can't find the ball $B_{r}(x,\epsilon)$ in $\left(\mathbb{R}^2, d_{r} \right)$, which is a subset of diamond. So $B((0,0),1)$, which is open in Euclidean space, is not open in $\left(\mathbb{R}^2, d_{r} \right)$.

I will be grateful for any help and hints, because topology is still a hard topic for me.

Comment: How is "jungle river metric" defined?

Comment: @Troposphere  This question has the [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092807/show-that-the-jungle-river-barbed-wire-metric-is-a-metric)

Comment: About jungle metric that Pumpkin hasn't defined: https://www.geogebra.org/m/FddDg7Ew

Comment: An interesting explanation for people like me who are not Tarzan: https://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=2239843

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning doesn't work. It goes wrong at the end of

> But there is a point $x \in B((0,0),1)$ in $\left(\mathbb{R}^2, \lVert\cdot \lVert_{2} \right)$, which doesn't belongs to diamond and we can't find the ball $B_{r}(x,\epsilon)$ in $\left(\mathbb{R}^2, d_{r} \right)$, which is a subset of diamond

In order for the ball to be open in $d_r$ all you need is to find a $B_r(x,\varepsilon)$ that is a subset of the *ball* -- it doesn't need to be a subset of the diamond $B_r(0,1)$.

---

In fact it *is* true that every open set according to $\|{\cdot}\|_2$ is also open according to $d_r$.

This is because we always have $d_r(x,y) \ge \|x-y\|_2$, and therefore $B_r(x,\varepsilon) \subseteq B_2(x,\varepsilon)$.

Now suppose $A\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ is open according to $\|{\cdot}\|_2$. We want to prove it is open according to $d_r$. To do this, by definition, we must take an *arbitrary* $x\in A$ and find a $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_r(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq A$. However, since $A$ is open in $\|{\cdot}\|_2$ there is a $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_2(x,\varepsilon)\subseteq A$, and therefore
$$ B_r(x,\varepsilon) \subseteq B_2(x,\varepsilon) \subseteq A$$

Comment: thank you for your answer too! I notice my mistake...

Answer (score 0):

If $B((p,q),r)$ is any Euclidean open ball, consider $(p',q')$ in it. If $q' \neq 0$, then $B_r((p',q'), |q'|)$ only contains points on the line $x=p'$ and so for a small enough $r' \le |q'|$ we will stay inside $B((p,q),r)$ with a ball $B_r((p',q'), r')$.

If $q'=0$ we have a $\|\cdot\|_1$ ball around $(p',q')$ that sits inside $B((p,q),r)$ and that is also te river-metric ball around such a point.

So all points of $B((p,q),r)$ are river-metric interior points, so the ball is open in the river metric topology.

Comment: thank you for your answer! now it's more clear for me